# Guide me about updating app without using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am a new learner of android. I am working on intents right now. I am reading about intents I have few questions about the intents which are bothering my mind if any one can clear the confusion I will be obliged. Questions are :

1. If we want to upgrade(switch between activities) an app we are using intent. without using intent are there any other possibilities to switch between activities it.
2. If they are there how can an app update itself.
3. In what scenario does a good app do it? and in what scenario does a bad app do it?

If anyone can answer these questions in detail or can guide me to a useful resource it will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Applications are not 'upgraded' through the intent system. Look into the `package manager` and other aosp system code for that

Intents are either explicit:

- I want to open SettingsActivity.java.

or Intents are implicit:

- I want to send this text as an email.

*These don't have anything to do with upgrading.*

Comment: By updating i meant switching between activities i know we can switch between activities by calling intent but can u do it without using intent.

Comment: You could switch out the views `ViewGroup.removeView` and add new views. But to switch between activities - you have to use `Intent`

Comment: so this means to switch between activities other than intent there is no way to do it. Ok so In what scenario does a good app do it? and in what scenario does a bad app do it(means switch using the app)?

Comment: All apps should use the `Intent` system to switch between Activities, why would you not want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Intents are either used to trigger an action or launch an Activity. They are not used for updating or upgrading any app.

Comment: By updating i meant switching between activities i know we can switch between activities by calling intent but can u do it without using intent.

Comment: No. You can return to your parent activity from your child Activity without using an intent. This can be done by using finish() method inside your child activity but, you can't launch a new activity without an Intent. Please note, in order for finish() to work, your parent activity should be below the child activity in the activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

For updating an app by itself you sholud have a server to get latest version of app. Every time when app lunches, it should call the server and get the version. If it has diffrence with what is defined in manifest, there is an update.

Now for do updating, you can pass the direct link to browser by intent so that the browser download it or you can download apk file by yourself using Http client from your direct link.